# Is there any way to keep all scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I need to write a program which reads a list of integers using scanf() (no using arrays). The first number is the representative exchange rate, and all remaining numbers represents cash amounts in dollars. The program should print the cash amount in dollars in "$" column and print in the "IS" column the cash amounts in the other coin (dollar*rate). In addition, program should print the sum of each column.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    float rate = 0;
    float numDollar = 0;
    float numShekel = 0;
    float sumDollar = 0;
    float sumShekel = 0;


    printf(" \nPlease enter the U.S Dollar Representative Exchange Rate \n ");
    scanf(" %f", &rate);

    printf(" \nPlease enter the numbers which represents cash amount in Dollars (and then press enter) \n ");

    printf("\n$\t\t\t\t\tIS\n");

    while (scanf(" %f", &numDollar) !=EOF && (numDollar!='\n'))
    {
      sumDollar = sumDollar + numDollar;
      numShekel = numDollar * rate;
      sumShekel = sumShekel + numShekel;

      printf("%3.2f\t\t\t\t\t%3.2f\n",numDollar,numShekel);
    }

     printf("%3.2f\t\t\t\t\t%3.2f\n",sumDollar,sumShekel);

    return 0;
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Based on the above program:

   user enters "rate" -> press enter key -> "enter list of numbers" ->
   press enter key.

   The problem: I want to print the column headers ($ and IS) only
   AFTER the above flow (i.e only AFTER user entered a list of integers
   and pressed enter key).

   I can`t just do the printing after the while loop, because then the
   columns headers will be printed below the columns values which is
   wrong. This is because I am restricted to print the next integer
   during the while loop because scanf will lose the previous value
   once the next one is read (correct?!)...

   **Is there any way to iterate through all the integers stored in scanf buffer?** so I can print the headers
   and then the values in one shot?
2. In the above program, it seems that after all the column values are
   printed, the sum of each column is not printed until CTRL+D is
   entered. How can I make the sum to be printed also with the column
   values in one shot? I tried to change the while condition to != '\n'
   but it does not work because I am dealing with float and not char.

you can assume the list of integers are entered in a single line.

Please assist.

Thanks

---

I did a few changes.

Now I am left only with the 2nd problem. How can I print the sum with the columns headers in 1 shot? I don`t want to press CTRL+D and only then have the sum printed. I want columns Headers + Column Values + Columns Sum to be printed in one shot.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    float rate = 0;
    float numDollar = 0;
    float numShekel = 0;
    float sumDollar = 0;
    float sumShekel = 0;


    printf(" \nPlease enter the U.S Dollar Representative Exchange Rate, and a list of cash amounts in Dollars in a single line (CTRL+D to finish) \n ");
    scanf(" %f", &rate);

    printf("\n$\t\t\t\t\tIS\n");

    while (scanf("%f", &numDollar) != EOF)
    {
      sumDollar = sumDollar + numDollar;
      numShekel = numDollar * rate;
      sumShekel = sumShekel + numShekel;

      printf("%3.2f\t\t\t\t\t%3.2f\n",numDollar,numShekel);
    }

     printf("%3.2f\t\t\t\t\t%3.2f\n",sumDollar,sumShekel);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `numDollar!='\n'` to do, given that `numDollar` is a `float` ?

Comment: `(numDollar!='\n')` is wrong but will compile because C will infer a cast from `int` (which is what `'\n'` is, like it or not) to `float`. So it'll be a check to see if `numDollar` is 10 or 13, depending on platform.

Comment: I don`t expect it. I was just thinking in loud. Is there anyway to iterate through all numbers stored in scanf buffer?

Comment: But why not use arrays? Why invent ridiculous mechanism to store list of values?

Comment: I agree, but this is what university wants. I was not asked to store the values, just to print them in a table with the columns headers. Is there anyway to print the header table AFTER the list of values are read by scanf?

Comment: @qwerty this task doesn't make any sense. Why would you want to print header after data is collected? Or what is wrong with storing data?

Comment: Andrey, I did not say I want to print the Headers below the data! Anyway, please reply to my latest input. I did some code changes, and now I am left only with 1 problem. PSB (Please See Below)

Comment: "Is there anyway to print the header table AFTER the list of values are read by scanf?" -- No, there is not, because `scanf` *does not* store past input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do isn't possible with just `scanf` and `printf` and without using arrays. You'd need to take over the character-by-character input system, using something like the `readline` library or the `terminfo` library.

The fundamental problem is that `scanf(' %f', ...)` will scan until it reads a floating point value, discarding all whitespace until then. "Whitespace" here not only means spaces and tabs but line ends as well! So the user can type RETURN a few times, the number, RETURN a few more, the second number, and RETURN before your code even gets to it. Your code would then need to obliterate all this malformatted input, work its way back up to the proper line, which may well have scrolled away by then, and print the properly formatted values.

Thus you need something better than `scanf` which will be able to *block* RETURN (and ENTER and long lines) from scrolling the screen, and you need `terminfo` or equivalent to get the control sequences needed to do things like "erase this line" and "move cursor to this point".

`scanf` is no substitute for a robust parser, unfortunately. It's designed around reading input files and isn't very smart about terminal input.

Comment: _What you want to do isn't possible with just scanf and printf and without using arrays_...  Can't be any plainer than that!

Answer (score 1):

1. This will print the sum first as desired, but will print the entered *Dollars* in reverse order.
   So far, dollar input order and printing order not specified.
2. A kludge to detect `\n` is far below.

Recommend `double` with money variables.

Always check `scanf()` results.  E.g. `EOF`, `0`, `1`

Space not needed in `scanf(" %f",...`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void GetMoney(double rate, double *sumDollar, double *sumShekel) {
  double numShekel, numDollar;
  int cnt = scanf("%lf", &numDollar);
  if (cnt == EOF) {
    printf("%3.2lf\t\t\t\t\t%3.2lf\n", *sumDollar, *sumShekel);
    return;
  }
  if (cnt != 1) Handle_NonNumericInput();  // e.g. do same as EOF
  numShekel = numDollar * rate;
  *sumDollar += numDollar;
  *sumShekel += numShekel;
  GetMoney(rate, sumDollar, sumShekel);
  printf("%3.2lf\t\t\t\t\t%3.2lf\n", numDollar, numShekel);
}

int main() {
  double sumDollar = 0.0;
  double sumShekel = 0.0;
  double rate;
  //...
  printf("\n$\t\t\t\t\tIS\n");
  GetMoney(rate, &sumDollar, &sumShekel);
  //...
}
```

--

Concerning *money*, values in this case, that have fractional parts like $0.005 cause issues.  Various approaches, do everything is the lowest legal unit like $0.01 --> 1 and $1.00 --> 100 **OR** round computation:

```
 sumDollar = round((sumDollar + numDollar)*100)/100;
 numShekel = round((numDollar * rate)*100)/100;
```

The issue of how to *best* handle money is beyond the scope of this post.  This is just an FYI that there exist special financial computation issues.

---

Reading a line of numbers spaced with white-space (except `'\n'`) and then finally terminated with `'\n'` is possible with `scanf()` (and `ungetc()`), but not worthy of coding except as an exercise as using `fgets()` and `sscanf()/strtod()` is far better.  But `fgets()` uses a `char` array, banned by the post.

The below somewhat works, but is not robust:

```
char ch == '\n'; 
int cnt = scanf("%f%c", &numDollar, &ch);
if (cnt == EOF) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (cnt == 0 || !isspace((unsigned char) ch)) Handle_BadInput();
Process(numDollar);
if (ch == '\n') Handle_ThisIsTheLastOne();
// Handle More
```

The above gets fooled if a space and `\n` follow a number.

Answer (score 0):

scanf() if successful returns the total number of characters read, otherwise a negative number is returned. so can check,

```
scanf(...)>0 or scanf(...)!=-1
```

condition.
scanf() needs cntrl+D, it treats '\n' as other white spaces so to end reading input on `enter` use `fgets()`. you can then convert the string to float using `atof()` or `strtof()`